# How to add one year to a date and select a particular month

Tags: c#, datetime

If the `NextInspectionDueDate` is less than or equal to today's date then I want to update it's value to the same day but next year and specifically the month of April.

I have tried the below but it gives an 'has some invalid arguments' error.
I just can't figure out the correct syntax. Maybe I should be doing it a different way?

```
if (foundVehicle.Vehicle.NextInspectionDueDate <= DateTime.Now)
{
    foundVehicle.Vehicle.NextInspectionDueDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), 4);
}
```

Comment: What if today is `31 Jan`? Shall the result be `30 Apr` or `1 May`?

Comment: You have to put `Day`: `... new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), 4, 1);` to have `1 Apr 2018`

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddYears` returns a `System.DateTime`. You need an `int`.

Comment: As a side note: perhaps [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) is of interest to you too.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp, correct, also the sample code provided would not even compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just forgotten a parameter for the constructor (the day of the month):

```
foundVehicle.Vehicle.NextInspectionDueDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year, 4, 1);
```

Comment: Your original answer was exactly what I was looking for. Your edit answer was not required as I specifically wanted the 1st of April. I have edited the question to include this. Thank you!

Comment: @RMadd Thanks for commenting! I will remove the edit than! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have one missing parameter (day), maybe you can try:

`var tempdate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
 foundVehicle.Vehicle.NextInspectionDueDate = new DateTime(tempdate.Year, 4, tempdate.Day);`

If you need to keep current date day

Or

`var day = foundVehicle.Vehicle.NextInspectionDueDate.Day;
 var tempdate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
 foundVehicle.Vehicle.NextInspectionDueDate = new DateTime(tempdate.Year, 4, day);`

If you need to keep original date day